# How can I sniff all DNS records from kuberenetes?

Tags: kubernetes, dns, sniffer, coredns

I wish to sniff and extract all DNS records from kubernetes: clientIP,serverIP,date,QueryType etc...
I had set up a kuberenetes service.
It is online and running. There I created several containerized micro-services that generate DNS queries (HTTP requests to external addresses). How can I see sniff it ? Is there a way to extract logs with DNS records ?

Comment: Which dns server are you using - codedns or kube-dns?

Comment: coredns is my dns server

Answer (score 1):

Given that you use CoreDNS as your cluster DNS service you can configure it to [log](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/blob/master/plugin/log/README.md) queries, errors etc. to `stdout`. CoreDNS have been available as an alternative to `kube-dns` since k8s version 1.11, so if you're running a cluster of version >1.11 there's a good chance that you're using CoreDNS.

The CoreDNS service usually™️ lives in the `kube-system` namespace and can be reconfigured using the provided ConfigMap.

Example on how to log everything to `stdout`, taken from the [README](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/tree/master/plugin/log):

```
. {
    ...
    log
    ...
}
```

When you've reconfigured CoreDNS you can check the Pod logs with:

`kubectl logs -n kube-system <POD NAME>`

Comment: Hi thanks for the replay.
I am using CoreDNS, but didn't understand from your answer how to extract the DNS logs. What files do I need to edit or reconfigure ? 
Can I see DNS requests from within the container in outer log file ?
TIA

Comment: @giladrosenthal OK, so if you do a `kubectl get configmap -n kube-system` there should be a ConfigMap (configuration) named something with CoreDNS. You can edit that to add the `log` option i mentioned in my answer. In my cluster the ConfigMap is called `coredns` so if i run the following command i can read the configuration of CoreDNS (in yaml): `kubectl get configmap -n kube-system coredns -o yaml`. When you've edit the config you should be able to read the logs with `kubectl logs` of the CoreDNS Pods.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully extracted DNS logs , using answer above. My new problem is that I can't see resolution data, i.e. RRDATA, such as resolved IP or other response info?